# OpenShift and Restheart

Tags: openshift, restheart

I have to use [Restheart APIs](http://restheart.org/) in an [OpenShift](https://www.openshift.com/) application.
I tried to execute restheart.jar as suggested in the installation and use guide, but it produced an error, due to the difference between the installed java version (openjdk 7) and the required one (oracle java 8).
Is there any trick to get Restheart APIs working in an OpenShift app?

Answer (score 0):

OpenShift does not support JDK 8 but that doesn’t mean you can’t run Java 8 applications.

You can use a DIY cartridge and install your own JDK version.